# Inserting data from one table based on some Id in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with almost 13,000 records and looks something like this

TableA:

```
ID  Status  Option
----------------------
1 |  Approved  |
2 |  Reject    |
3 |  Approved  |
4
.
.
13,000
```

TableB

```
 Name    Option                      Status
-----------------------------------------------
 First  | {'data':'Add into box','ID':'1'}  |  Approved 
 Second | {'data':'Don't Add','ID':'2'}     |  Reject
 Third  | {'data':'Add into box','ID':'3'}  |  Approved 
.
.
.
13,000
```

I want to fill the `Option` column (data type `varchar`)in table A with similar data to that of Table B `Option` column (data type B) based on same ID which is also in option json object. How do i fill them in one go rather than going one by one.

Comment: Your using a RDBMS, so just define the relationship. It `TableB` add column `status_id` then update `status_id`, create a FK to `TableA`,  finally drop `status` column from `TableB`.

Answer (score 1):

An update query where we set the "option" in TableA using a subquery, where we filter the result based on "id" of TableA matching with "id" inside varchar column "option" of TableB.

```
update tablea 
set option = (select option from tableb 
              where tablea.id::text = tableb.option::json ->> 'id' 
              limit 1);    
-- assuming id has a 1:1 relation in both tables
```

Comment: i think my previous explanation of question was not correct.I have updated the table structure.Can you help in that

Comment: pls check now. Have updated the access of id from column to varchar json as per your changes.

Comment: yes it has worked,i was trying to do something with joins but your method of adding limit 1 in the end is much easier

Comment: hi is there any way this query can be optimized because it takes lots of time when i have close to 100,000 records